# Orchard: I enable the code generation but its not working

Tags: orchardcms, orchard-modules

I use latest version of Orchard 
I enable codegen with two mode: Command-line or UI 
however I got the succeed message : codegen was enabled 
but when I want to create module such as: codegen module MyModule 
I encountering with this message:error executing command "codegen module MyModule"

 No command found matching arguments "codegen module MyModule"

?

Comment: Look in the logs under your Orchard.Web/App_Data/Logs

Comment: I found the log file "orchard-recipes-2015.08.13" but the content is empty

Comment: You probably haven't started the application yet? You first have to cook a recipe before you can enable any modules

Comment: He said he tried from the UI, so the application has to be up. Does the feature appear as enabled in the Modules screen?

Comment: sure, I started the application, and I see the codegen mudle, even in UI when I click for enable then search for codegen I see again didn't enable!,

Comment: Did you by any chance install codegen from the gallery? If so, that's the problem: there is no need to install it as it comes standard with Orchard. The version on the gallery is for older versions of Orchard.

Comment: thanks friends for helping me, I install the Orchard on IIS then it's worked!

Answer (score 1):

I had this same issue. I am running version 1.10.1 from a fork of the git repo.

You might have to blow away your database if you attempted to install it already and it is in an inconsistent state. If this is not an option you will need to manually remove it from the db and potentially a manifest file, I can't guide you on that.

1. Ensure you have run the application and completed initial setup (cooked a recipe).
2. Close visual studio and any other applications that might have a file lock in your Orchard.Web directory.
3. Run the orchard command line tool `...\Orchard\src\Orchard.Web\bin\orchard.exe` then call `feature enable Orchard.CodeGeneration`
4. Ensure the codegen commands appear when you type `help commands` to confirm successful install.